# Unable to add application to sharepoint

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-addin

I have a sharepoint 2013 application. There's essentially nothing in it other than the default pages/scripts/files

In the app manifest, I went to add permissions to certain things such as

- Web -- Read
- Tenant -- REad
- User Profiles -- Read
- List -- Read Site
- Collection -- Read

I package the app, upload it to the app catalogue, select the application to install and I get a message saying

> "you can't add this app here"

When I remove the permissions from the app, I am able to upload the app and install it just fine.

Why is this? How can I deploy the application and install it with the permissions I want to set

Comment: Are you getting the issue even when you applied only "List - Read" permission?
Can you apply one permission at a time to the app to isolate the issue?

Comment: I narrowed it down to the User Profiles - Read permission. It would not let me add the app if this permission was present. Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and believe the answer lies in this statement at this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163864.aspx

> Apps that request rights for the User Profiles scope must be installed
>   by a **tenant administrator**, and they cannot be installed in Office 365
>   Small Business Premium version of SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 0):

The user must have required permissions to deploy based on the APP permissions.

1. Tenant scope - Tenant admin
2. Site collection - site collection admin
3. Web - Site owner
4. User profile - Tenant admin
5. List - Site owner

Try with Tenant admin rights in your case. I can provide additional information if needed.

Thanks,
Venkat Knjeti